# Top: how to view the full command path?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, mojave

Is it possible, using `top`, to view the full path of the running processes/commands? I [tried](https://linoxide.com/linux-command/linux-top-command-examples-screenshots/) pressing <kbd>C</kbd> on my keyboard but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: top]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `htop` instead of regular `top`. It shows the full process name by default and I find it easier to use.

You can install it with [brew.sh](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install htop
```

[image: picture of htop running]
<sup>(I've blocked out my name with red)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for Top type output with full path

I suggest `ps ax` sorted by PID

or even better `ps auxww` sorted by CPU